Package Installation Wizard does not work
Package installation wizard is not working. After building and publishing my solution its broken not sure what is causing the issue.
Can someone please help to fix this ? Sitecore 9.2





Can you please attach the exception on the Sitecore logs?

Can you also please attach a screenshot of the request(s) that are failing in the network tab of your browser developer tools?

added both log and network tab error.

What is the full url of that failed request?
